# Rearranging Data Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate some help to find a correct approach to solve my issue.

I am attempting to loop through all worksheets (except for "Sheet 1" and "Output".

All the above referenced worksheets contain data from cell A2 to last column and last row. I need to copy all the looped ranges (one below the other) in cell C2 in my "Output" worksheet.

Also I have a unique number in A1 in all worksheets (except for "Sheet 1" and "Output" that needs to be copied into B2 in my "Output" worksheet. The trick is (which i am struggling with) the value in A1 needs to be copied down B2 in my "Output" worksheet by the number A2:last row in all my looped worksheets.

Below is my code thus far:

```
Sub EveryDayImShufflingData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim maxRow As Integer
    Dim x As String

    Set PasteSheet = Worksheets("Output")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loop through worksheets except "Sheet 1" and "Output"
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (ws.Name <> "Sheet1") And (ws.Name <> "Output") And (ws.Visible = True) Then

            'Select the Worksheet
            ws.Select

            'With each worksheet
            With ws

                'Declare variables lRow and lCol
                lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                lCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                'Set range exc. VIN
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

                'Paste the range into "Output" worksheet
                Rng.Copy
                PasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                x = .Cells(1, 1).Value

                For i = 1 To lRow
                    PasteSheet.Cells(i, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = x
                    maxRow = maxRow + 1
                Next

                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True

            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be kindly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub EveryDayImShufflingData()    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, copyRng As Range, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, PasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set PasteSheet = Worksheets("Output")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (ws.Name <> "Sheet1") And (ws.Name <> "Output") And (ws.Visible = True) Then

            lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            Set copyRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol))

            copyTargetCell = PasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            copyRng.Copy Destination:=PasteSheet.Range("C" & copyTargetCell)

            Worksheets("Output").Range("B" & copyTargetCell & ":B" & (copyTargetCell + copyRng.Rows.Count - 1)) = ws.Range("A1")
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you Alex P! Worked a charm.

Comment: If i wanted to add another layer of complexity to your code and in Cell A2 in "Output" - INDEX (A2:A & lastrow) in "Sheet1", MATCH (B2, (B2:B & lastrow,0) in "Output". How can i achieve this and fill down formula to last row

Comment: Sorry B2:B & lastrow in Sheet1